# Runtime error SIGTSTP in below c++ program

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I stuck at a problem [Minion chef and Bananas](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MINEAT) .Which is a binary search based problem

I execute the below program on following test cases;
And it successfully passed all the test cases

Test case 1:

> 3 3
>
> 1 2 3

Output:

> 3

Test case 2:

> 3 4
>
> 1 2 3

Output:

> 2

Test case 3:

> 4 5
>
> 4 3 2 7

Output:

> 4

But I am when I am submitting the Below program I am getting the error as "SIGTSTP"
Please help.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int getHours(vector<int> piles,int k){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<piles.size();i++){
        if(piles[i]%k==0)
            sum+=(piles[i]/k);
        else
            sum+=(1+piles[i]/k);
    }
    return sum;
}


int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        int h;
        cin>>n>>h;
        vector <int> piles;
        int tempmax = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int temp;
            cin>>temp;
            tempmax = max(temp,tempmax);
            piles.push_back(temp);
        }
        int low = 0;
        int high = tempmax;
        if(tempmax==1){
            cout<<h<<endl;
            continue;
        }

        while(low<high){
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
            int p=getHours(piles,mid);
            if(p<=h)
                high = mid;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        cout<<low<<endl;
        piles.clear();

    }


}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `SIGTSTP` is sent to a program, when it is being killed. So, probably, your code took to much time to execute ("_Time Limit: 2 secs_"), ad was killed, which resulted in such signal.

Comment: All of your test cases are fairly short, but the problem could be throwing billions of numbers at you. Ensure that when faced with extremely large `N` and `H` that the program does not take excessively long.

Comment: Unrelated: Consider changing `int getHours(vector<int> piles,int k)` to `int getHours(const vector<int> &piles,int k)` so that `piles` isn't copied every time the function is called.

Comment: still showing the same error @user4581301

Comment: If you can find the test case that is making this fail we may be able to help, but the answer will probably still be  "Your program is too slow. You will have to find a different algorithm." Sidenote: [`endl` is very expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n). Prefer `'\n'` if all you want is a new line.

Comment: When i changed to `'\n' ` now it is giving as SIGFPE

Comment: @coders4521 [`SIGFPE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html) may indicate a bug in your code: floating point exception.

Comment: You can divide by zero in `getHours` if the second parameter is zero. And it can be zero if `mid=0`, which is possible when `low=0` and `high=1` (which is theoretically possible after a single iteration of the binary search, if you don't examine exact logic behind the program).

Comment: I used `assert(k!=0)` My program terminated with error But i am not getting where i am doing mistake.

Comment: `assert` does nothing if the program is not compiled for debugging. If debugging is on, `assert` spits out an error message and terminates the program. Not what you want to use here. You need to PREVENT the error.

Comment: Sidenote: SIGFPE has been broadened over the years to cover a wider variety of mathematical errors. Do not assume it's strictly floating point.

Comment: `SIGTSTP` is used to *suspend* processes from the terminal (usually with `^Z`).  You **can’t** *kill* a process with it!